# Deserializing JsonResponse to a C# Object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON response using a JSON to C# converter.
I've never had a problem before, but with this response the result of the conversion is quite strange.

Anyway, this is the response:

```
{
    "get": "standings",
    "parameters": {
        "league": "520",
        "season": "2020"
    },
    "errors": [],
    "results": 1,
    "response": [
        {
            "league": {
                "id": 520,
                "name": "Acreano",
                "country": "Brazil",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/520.png",
                "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/br.svg",
                "season": 2020,
                "standings": [
                    [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 1228,
                                "name": "Galvez",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1228.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 2nd Phase",
                            "form": null,
                            "status": "same",
                            "description": "Next Round",
                            "all": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 2,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 10478,
                                "name": "Humaitá",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10478.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 2nd Phase",
                            "form": null,
                            "status": "same",
                            "description": "Next Round",
                            "all": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 3,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 10854,
                                "name": "Náuas",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10854.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 2nd Phase",
                            "form": null,
                            "status": "same",
                            "description": null,
                            "all": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 4,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 6370,
                                "name": "Vasco da Gama AC",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/6370.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 2nd Phase",
                            "form": null,
                            "status": "same",
                            "description": null,
                            "all": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 1228,
                                "name": "Galvez",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/1228.png"
                            },
                            "points": 9,
                            "goalsDiff": 12,
                            "group": "Acreano: 1st Phase",
                            "form": "WWW",
                            "status": "same",
                            "description": "Next Round",
                            "all": {
                                "played": 3,
                                "win": 3,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 14,
                                    "against": 2
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 1,
                                "win": 1,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 2,
                                    "against": 1
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 2,
                                "win": 2,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 12,
                                    "against": 1
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 2,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 10478,
                                "name": "Humaitá",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10478.png"
                            },
                            "points": 6,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 1st Phase",
                            "form": "WWL",
                            "status": "up",
                            "description": "Next Round",
                            "all": {
                                "played": 3,
                                "win": 2,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 1,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 5,
                                    "against": 5
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 2,
                                "win": 1,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 1,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 1,
                                    "against": 4
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 1,
                                "win": 1,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 4,
                                    "against": 1
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 3,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 10854,
                                "name": "Náuas",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10854.png"
                            },
                            "points": 3,
                            "goalsDiff": 3,
                            "group": "Acreano: 1st Phase",
                            "form": "LWL",
                            "status": "down",
                            "description": null,
                            "all": {
                                "played": 3,
                                "win": 1,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 2,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 6,
                                    "against": 3
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 1,
                                "win": 1,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 5,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 2,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 2,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 1,
                                    "against": 3
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 4,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 6370,
                                "name": "Vasco da Gama AC",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/6370.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": -15,
                            "group": "Acreano: 1st Phase",
                            "form": "LLL",
                            "status": "up",
                            "description": null,
                            "all": {
                                "played": 3,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 3,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 2,
                                    "against": 17
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 2,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 2,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 2,
                                    "against": 12
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 1,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 1,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 5
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "rank": 5,
                            "team": {
                                "id": 10853,
                                "name": "Independência",
                                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10853.png"
                            },
                            "points": 0,
                            "goalsDiff": 0,
                            "group": "Acreano: 1st Phase",
                            "form": null,
                            "status": "down",
                            "description": null,
                            "all": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "home": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "played": 0,
                                "win": 0,
                                "draw": 0,
                                "lose": 0,
                                "goals": {
                                    "for": 0,
                                    "against": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "update": "2020-04-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the resulting object.

```
public class Parameters
    {
        public string league { get; set; }
        public string season { get; set; }
    }

    public class League
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
        public int season { get; set; }
        public IList<IList<>> standings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public League league { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string get { get; set; }
        public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
        public IList<object> errors { get; set; }
        public int results { get; set; }
        public IList<Response> response { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, there is a strange public `IList<IList<>> standings { get; set; }`.
I think that it could depend on the double square brackets on the standing tag, but I've not been working with Json objects so much.

Comment: Do you generate your c# code somewhow?

Comment: In the json, Standings is a collection of 2 items and each item is a collection itself, so to deserialize it you need that list of lists. What is the problem exactly? Do you want all subitems merged into a single list?

Comment: @sommmen - Yes, I'm using JSon to c# Converter. When I have no arrays like this, it works correctly.

Comment: @FrancescCastells - As I said, the problem is that I usually deserialize the response to the class given by the tool, and it works. With this situation, the converter cannot create a proper class for the deserialization.

Comment: @leotato008 okay - switch to a different tool and see if that works. i've added a sample with a generator that works - apperently this one does not. The json is valid anyways. If you want to keep using that tool atleast provide a link to where we can find the tool.

Comment: @leotato008 you said the result "is strange" not that "it doesn't work". The List of Lists looks correct to me. If it doesn't work, post the exact error that you get and how to reproduce it.

Comment: @FrancescCastells - Sorry Francesc, but how can a thing like this work? public IList<IList<>>.. The list has no type. Anyway, this is the tool: https://www.jsonutils.com/

Comment: @sommmen - Thank you, I'll try your solution in a moment!

Comment: Ah sorry, @leotato008, I was focussing on the fact that there's a list inside a list and I completely missed the missing type in the inner list. Of course, you are missing the Standing type. Sorry about that.

Comment: @sommmen - BINGO! Thank you veru much, the solution provided works perfectly! I'll switch to this QuickType at once!

Comment: @FrancescCastells - Don't worry! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you're doing - it most like is because there's an array of arrays (a list of lists w/e) in your json that something can't handle.

If i pass this through [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) i get the following which seems better to me;

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var myObj = MyObj.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class MyObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("get")]
        public string Get { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("errors")]
        public List<object> Errors { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public long Results { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("response")]
        public List<Response> Response { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Parameters
    {
        [JsonProperty("league")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long League { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("season")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Season { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty("league")]
        public League League { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class League
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("logo")]
        public Uri Logo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("flag")]
        public Uri Flag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("season")]
        public long Season { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("standings")]
        public List<List<Standing>> Standings { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Standing
    {
        [JsonProperty("rank")]
        public long Rank { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("team")]
        public Team Team { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("points")]
        public long Points { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("goalsDiff")]
        public long GoalsDiff { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("group")]
        public string Group { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("form")]
        public string Form { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("all")]
        public All All { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("home")]
        public All Home { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("away")]
        public All Away { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("update")]
        public DateTimeOffset Update { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class All
    {
        [JsonProperty("played")]
        public long Played { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("win")]
        public long Win { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("draw")]
        public long Draw { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lose")]
        public long Lose { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("goals")]
        public Goals Goals { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Goals
    {
        [JsonProperty("for")]
        public long For { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("against")]
        public long Against { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Team
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("logo")]
        public Uri Logo { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MyObj
    {
        public static MyObj FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this MyObj self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            long l;
            if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
            {
                return l;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (long)untypedValue;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
    }
}
```

Notice this:

```
[JsonProperty("standings")]
public List<List<Standing>> Standings { get; set; }
```

You can also see it better if you throw it in some online editor like  https://jsoneditoronline.org

[image]